# Bring the Android app to foreground after recieving a notification push like the application launcher

Tags: android, android-intent

In my case, I receive a notification message and open an Activity say 'X'. After closing it I want to bring my application again to foreground like the behavior of the Application launcher.

In more details I want to see if my app in the background, bring it to foreground. If not, restart it.
Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getRunningAppProcesses() in ActivityManager`. And then check your **package** name in the list of running Processes.

Comment: Great I'm doing that. Can you tell me how to order my app to come to foreground without starting it from scratch?

Comment: This should do the trick.

<activity ... android:launchMode="singleTop" />
When you create an intent to start the app use:

Intent intent= new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
This is that should be needed.

Comment: Thanks alot Sandy. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

if you need to start or open your activity when user click on `Notification` then just use `Intent`  to call your main activity or home page that's it. have you Google your problem?
See the documents of Notification [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html)
and for [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)
it may helpful for you

Comment: I did, I just want to bring my application to foreground (if it's in the background) without starting it from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

Use C2DM  - cloud to device message to listen for the notification and launch your app.

Comment: Thanks alot for your replay ... Actually I'm doing that but I want to know how to bring my application again to foreground without reopening it from scratch. Any help?

Comment: Use Activity Launcher attribute of singleTask  to reuse the existing Activity